# Como descobrir o tipo de uma variável dada pelo usuário?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis, pycharm

Gostaria de pedir que o usuário digitasse alguma coisa e descobrir qual o tipo do que ele escreveu. Até agora eu só conheço o `input()`, mas o `input()` só retorna o tipo `String`. Se eu por `int(input())` ou `float(input())` caio no mesmo problema:

Não posso fazer:

```
n = input()  
if n == int:  
  print('Tente novamente')
```

e nem:

```
n = int(input())  
if n == str:  
  print('Tente novamente')
```

Pois eu já especifiquei o tipo da variável. Como eu faço pro programa descobrir o tipo para que eu efetue a condição com base no tipo dela?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mesmo que ele digite `1` ou `1.0` será `string` de qualquer forma, uma `string` pode ter formato numérico normalmente, só porque `1` é um numero não quer dizer que o tipo dele vai ser `int`.

O que você pode fazer é usar duas [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) para detectar qual formato a string **se assemelha** e então fazer o *cast*, por exemplo:

```
import re

entrada = input()

if re.match('^\d+$', entrada):
    entrada = int(entrada)
elif re.match('^\d+\.\d+$', entrada):
    entrada = float(entrada)

print(type(entrada), entrada)
```

A regex `^\d+$` da primeira `if` vai procurar do começo ao fim da string se tem o formato de numero, sem ponto.

A regex `^\d+\.\d+$` da primeira `if` vai procurar do começo ao fim da string que comece com formato numérico até chegar a um ponto, assim que chegar no ponto irá procurar o numero após ele, se ocorrer o `match` irá entrar na if

Acaso não reconheça nenhum ele irá imprimir como `string` mesmo

---

### Sobre Python 2.7

Apenas para constar, na versão 2.7 do Python o [**`input()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) fazia a avaliada do conteúdo por conta própria (como se rodasse o *"eval"*), então se fizesse um script assim:

```
entrada = input()

print type(entrada), entrada
```

- Quando o input fosse `1` retornaria: `<type 'int'> 1`
- Quando o input fosse `1.0` retornaria: `<type 'float'> 1.0`
- Quando o input fosse `"1"` retornaria: `<type 'str'> "1"`

Então o equivalente do [**`input()`** do *Python 3*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) para o *Python 2* na verdade seria o [**`raw_input()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta está na pergunta. Não tem o que fazer. Você sempre saberá o tipo do valor, não importa como ele é obtido e saberá o tipo da variável naquele momento. Na verdade linguagens como Python não possuem tipos de variáveis, apenas uma etiqueta dizendo que tipo ela está representando naquele momento.

Se o código já sabe qual é o tipo não tem porque descobrir alguma coisa.

Se está usando uma função que recebe um valor que pode ser de vários tipos aí pode usar a função [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#type) para identificar qual é o tipo daquele objeto.

Comment: A pergunta é supondo justamente que eu não sei o que o usuário irá escrever. Ai aso ele escreva um número int() o programa irá realizar uma certa ação, já se escrever uma frase str() o programa irá executar outra ação... Aí como eu faço pra descobrir o tipo do que ele inseriu?

Comment: Isto que você está falando não existe. Se você quer verificar o conteúdo do texto, aí a pergunta é totalmente outra do que você escreveu, tipo é algo sabido.

Comment: Entendi, então vou refazer a pergunta.

Comment: Aí você vai invalidar as respostas já postadas.

Comment: Não não, vou fazer outra pergunta, mas perguntando "Como verificar o conteúdo do texto: se é int, float ou str?" Seria assim?

Comment: Aí sim. Mas parece que já aceitou uma resposta aqui. Isto não servirá para outras pessoas que procurem por descobrir o tipo da variável como está na pergunta e não o padrão de texto do dado, como parece ser o que deseja.

Answer (score 1):

Colega, utilizando o método eval() é possível pegar e interpretar o valor do dado inserido na variável. Exemplo:

```
numero = input()

try:
    if type(eval(numero)) == type(1):
        print("tipo inteiro")
    elif type(eval(numero)) == type(1.0):
        print("tipo real")
    else:
        print('não é um tipo numérico, %s' % type(numero))
except NameError as n:
    print('não é um tipo numérico, %s' % type(numero))
```

Talvez assim seja mais simples. **Lazy way mode**.

Comment: Tá dando erro quando eu ponho uma string(). Aparece isso:   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'teste' is not defined

Comment: acredito que agora funcione. Pode testar. Com eval, quando inserimos uma string ele reconhece apenas valores definidos no código.

Comment: Funcionou, agora me resta aprender a usar isso... Obrigado

Comment: Por quê exatamente fazer `type(1)` e `type(1.0)` se você sabe que os tipos serão `int` e `float`?

Comment: Seria apenas para comparar os resultados de strings, mas pode-se substituir por int ou float ou outro tipo que quiser. ele vai comparar.

Answer (score 1):

use a função isinstance(). Ex, quero verificar algo que o usuário digitou, se é um inteiro para selecionar alguma opção, basta:

```
valor = input("Digite um valor inteiro") // usuario digita "a"
print(isinstance(valor, int) // Saida = False
```

Claro que o valor que o usuário digita será sempre string, mas com essa função fica mais fácil o entendimento para conversão ou posteior conversão.

Comment: Mas acho que isso não foi o perguntado. Como bem disse, se o retorno será sempre *string*, a condição `isinstance(valor, int)` **sempre** será falsa, então não faz sentido usá-la. E se usar o `int` para converter, cairá na resposta do Maniero: se o programa sabe o tipo, não tem porque verificar. Então sua resposta ficou bem confusa e não deu para entender o que quis dizer. Aliás, comentários *inline* no Python usa-se `#`, não `//`.

Comment: Tudo que o usuário digita é string, porém, consigo converter uma string "1" para int, mas não consigo converter uma str "a" para int. Apesar de tudo ser string, nem tudo pode ser convertido, entendeu?  Ele pode por exemplo tentar converter o input e depois verificar se a conversão ocorreu corretamente e isinstance() é uma ótima forma para isso. Usado com try except então, ele solucionaria o problema. Mas quis apenas acrescentar algo. A maioria escreveu várias linhas pra fazer a mesma coisa que a função. Quanto aos comentários estou ciente, mas quis representar o debug se não entendeu.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma simples é utilizar a `ast.literal_eval`.

- [eval vs ast.literal_eval: quais as diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326937/5878)

Assim, você não abre brechas em segurança utilizando a função `eval`, nem precisa prever todos os formatos de entrada com expressões regulares.

```
import ast

while True:
    entrada = input('Entre com alguma coisa:')
    valor = ast.literal_eval(entrada)
    print(type(valor))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/UnrealisticLinedCable)</sup>

O resultado seria algo como:

```
>>> Entre com alguma coisa: 1
<class 'int'>
>>> Entre com alguma coisa: 3.14
<class 'float'>
>>> Entre com alguma coisa: 1,2,3
<class 'tuple'>
>>> Entre com alguma coisa: [1,2,3]
<class 'list'>
>>> Entre com alguma coisa: '1'
<class 'str'>
>>> Entre com alguma coisa: "1"
<class 'str'>
```