# como faço para este script funcionar?

Tags: python, python-3.x

eu sei que a variavel sempre vai ser str mas eu queria colocar um valor ali e caso fosse do tipo inteiro dai verificasse senão ele desse a mensagem  "Você tem que digita uma idade NUMERICA e não um texto ou numeros decimais!!"
e não um erro do programa em si.

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

ida = input("Digite um numero: ")

if ida == type(int):
    if int(ida) >= 18:
        print("Você é maior de idade!!")
    elif int(ida) < 18:
        print("Você é Menor de idade")
else:
    print("Você tem que digita uma idade NUMERICA e não um texto ou numeros decimais!!")
```

Comment: Tira o `if ida == type(int)`  pq o input não receberá inteiros (em python3) nunca.

Comment: Sugestão de como resolver: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263153/3635

Comment: nossa me ajudou bastante vlw... consegui aki!!