# Como faço para meu programa diferenciar um valor int e float

Tags: python

Galera...so novo no Python e queria uma ajuda, estou fazendo uma calculadora e usei a função isdigit() para evitar o erro da pessoa colocar um carácter não numerico, porem ela so reconhece números inteiro, queria ajuda para resolver isso(para a calculadora calcular numeros quebrados ) e também queria ajuda//dica para poder encurtar o código.

```
a = False
b = True
c = True
tipo = input("(-,+,*,/)\nqual função vc deseja fazer ? \n")

if tipo == "-" or tipo == "+" or tipo == "*" or tipo == "/":
    a = True
else:
    print("caracter invalido!")
    
if a == True:
    primeiro_numero = input("qual o primeiro numero da função ? \n")
    
    if not primeiro_numero.isdigit():
        print("Digite apenas numeros")
        b = False
   
    if b == True:
        
        segundo_numero = input("qual o segundo numero da função ? \n")
        if not segundo_numero.isdigit():
            print("Digite apenas numeros")
            c = False
            
        if c == True:
            
            if tipo == "+":
                final = int(primeiro_numero) + int(segundo_numero)

            elif tipo == "-":
                final = int(primeiro_numero) - int(segundo_numero)

            elif tipo == "/":
                final = int(primeiro_numero) / int(segundo_numero)

            elif tipo == "*":
                final = int(primeiro_numero) * int(segundo_numero)
    
            print("O resultado é ",final)
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como descobrir o tipo de uma variável dada pelo usuário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263149/como-descobrir-o-tipo-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-dada-pelo-usu%c3%a1rio) ... Porque a questão aqui é o numero digitado pelo usuário, sendo o numero digitado sempre será string, então com a regex que fiz é possivel fazer o parse mais adequado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma mais elegante de se testar é usando a builtin `isinstance`.

O uso dela é `isinstance(VARIAVEL, CLASSE)`

**Update**: usei o termo `classe` para que entendam que não necessariamente é um `type` primário.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> def is_int(x):
...     return isinstance(x, int)
...
>>> def is_float(x):
...     return isinstance(x, float)
...
>>> is_int(1)
True
>>> is_float(1)
False
>>> is_int(1.0)
False
>>> is_float(1.0)
True
>>>
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar:

```
try:
    numeroInteiro = int(input("Insira um numero inteiro: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Você deve inserir um valor inteiro!")
```

Se o usuário inserir qualquer coisa que não seja um inteiro, vai disparar a exceção, e esse trecho funciona com qualquer função do tipo, `str()`, `float()` e etc..

E em relação a encurtar o código, na parte da seleção da operação você pode armazenar todas as operações em uma lista, e usar os operadores `not in` pra saber se o usuário selecionou uma opção válida.

```
print("(-,+,*,/) qual função vc deseja fazer ? \n")
operadores = ['-', '+', '*', '/']

tipo = ''

while(tipo not in operadores):

    tipo = input("Selecione uma opção adequada! ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Para diferenciar tipos de variáveis em **Python**, existe a função **type()** que recebe por parametro uma variável, e retorna uma **metaclass** referente ao tipo de dado armazenado nela.

Exemplo para verificar se uma variável armazena um FLOAT:
`print(type(var) is float)`

Exemplo para verificar se uma variável armazena um INT:
`print(type(var) is int)`

Você pode rodar o script abaixo variando o valor de **var**.

```
var = 1.2
varType = type(var);

if varType is float:
    print("float")
elif varType is int:
    print("int")
```

[Saiba mais](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/#:%7E:text=Two%20different%20types%20of%20arguments,returns%20a%20new%20type%20object.)