# Quero evitar o ValueError nesse int(input()), mas não sei como

Tags: python, python-3.x

esse é um código básico pra meu curso em python em matemática, o professor disse que a menor quantidade de erro no código que encontra vai conseguir uma premiação, já fiz quase todos os testes de uso mas quando coloca um valor str no input a e b, ele para de executar o programa e eu não consigo evitar isso.

```
def aritmetico():
    a = float(a1)
    b = float(b1)
    if operacao == '+':
        resultado = a + b
        print(resultado)
    elif operacao == '-':
        resultado = a - b
        print(resultado)
    elif operacao == '*':
        resultado = a * b
        print(resultado)
    elif operacao == '/' and b != 0:
        resultado = a / b
        print(resultado)
    else:
        print('erro')


while True:

    print('Exemplo de simbolo de operação: Adição(+), Subtração(-), Multiplicação(*), Divisão(/).')
    operacao = input('Digite a operação: ')
    if operacao == '+' or operacao == '-' or operacao == '*' or operacao == '/':
        a1 = input('Primeiro número: ')
        b1 = input('Segundo número: ')
        aritmetico()
    elif operacao == 's':
        break
    else:
        print('operador errado, calculo invalido')
```

Comment: Isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263153/3635 resolve o seu problema?

Comment: Isso também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210010/5878

Comment: @Woss com certeza [`str.isdigit`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210021/3635) (https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) é uma boa, claro que no caso de float vai ter mais trabalho e se tiver números negativos vai ter que checar também, ainda sim uma melhor saída exception.

Comment: obrigado, acabei de implementar o str.isdigit e o codigo funcionou